# How to expand filenames that begins with a dash (-)

Tags: linux, bash

I know if you enclose a variable (that contains a filename) with double quotes, it will expand `$`, `*`s and backticks (`'`). For example `cmp "$file1" "$file2"` will be fine if both files contain `*`s at the beginning or anything else that's "normal". It won't work if the files have any number of dashes in the beginning though. Instead, it will try to do the literal meaning of -, treating it as an option. How do you get around this?

This will work:

```
var1=*file.txt
var2=*file2.txt

cmp "$var1" "$var2"
```

But

```
var1=-file.txt 
cmp "$var1" "$var2"
```

will say - is an unrecognized option. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most shell commands support a -- option to tell them that the remainder of the line are actual arguments, not options.

Answer (score 1):

Most commands will accept a `--` to mark the end of the parameter options, so `cmp -- "$var1" "$var2"` should work. It is not actually a problem about the shell expanding the value, but about the command itself interpreting the passed arguments as a file name or as an option.

Also, if they are files in the current directory you can do `cmp ./"$var1" ./"$var2"`.

Comment: The "./$var" trick will work as long as `var1` contains any relative path, i.e. doesn't not start with `/`.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested:

```
solaris10$ var3=-ts
solaris10$ var4=ts1
solaris10$ cmp -- "$var3" "$var4"
-ts ts1 differ: char 10, line 1
solaris10$
```

works just fine.